# Manter imagem junto ao texto dentro de um botão

Tags: android

Talvez seja uma situação simples, mas eu já quebrei um pouco a cabeça aqui e ainda não tive sucesso.

Eu tenho um botão, e dentro dele carrego uma imagem e um texto.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btNovaPreVenda"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/carrinhodecompras"
    android:paddingTop="1sp"
    android:text=" | Nova Pré-Venda"    
    android:textColor="@color/branco" />
```

Só que, pelo layout_width estar setado como `fill_parent`, a imagem fica na esquerda e o texto, fica centralizado. 
Porém, se eu colocar o layout_width como wrap_content, funciona porque o botão será criado do tamanho necessário.

Alguma ideia de como deixar o `layout_width` como `fill_parent` e a imagem ficar centralizada com o texto?

Atualmente, está [assim](http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/296/060/full/exemplo2.png?1403877768).
Gostaria de deixar [assim](http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/296/059/full/exemplo.png?1403877661)

Comment: tem como tirar um print para visualizar melhor

Comment: @RogersCorrêa - Add o print. Obrigado!

Comment: e vou te dizer que esteticamente a forma como está é bem mais bonita do que a que tu queres colocar... :P Como tu quer fazer, fica um um pouco desorganizado passa a impressão de bagunça o menu.(sinceridade). Acho melhor manter como está.

Comment: Eu tbm acho que do jeito que está (alinhado a esquerda) fica bom. Mas não aprovaram. Querem junto ao texto. kkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta colocar:

```
    android:paddingLeft="100dp"
    android:drawablePadding="-60dp"
```

Eu acabei de testar aqui e funcionou!!!

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda. Deu certo. \o/

Comment: Dinada! Fico à disposição, estamos aqui pra isso!

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou colocar
 `android:drawableRight=`
 ao invés de 
`android:drawableleft=`

ou coloca
`android:drawableleft=` com padding maior.
No carrinho de compras por exemplo.

Comment: Deu certo. Não tinha usado o android:paddingleft.  Obrigado.